# Does vim have autocomplete ability like Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vim autocomplete for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138039/vim-autocomplete-for-python)

I use eclipse at work. Eclipse has this amazing feature where it can autocomplete based on methods and classes in your project space (as opposed to just autocompleting in just this file).

Does vim have plugins that provide similar capabilities?

i.e. if I defined `foo()` in **a.py** editing **b.py** and typing `fo` will result in `foo()` being suggested??

Answer (score 0):

Vim doesn't provide *auto*-completion but it has what it calls *omni*-completion that is triggered by `<C-x><C-o>`. See `:h new-omni-completion`. There are other backends for Python omnicompletion like the promising [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) or [Pydiction](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=850). Try them if you don't like the default behaviour.

For *omni*-completion to become *auto*-completion, you'll need [a third party plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=completion&script_type=&order_by=creation_date&direction=descending&search=search) (yes, in case you didn't notice, Vim is a text editor, not an IDE) like [AutoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879), which I use. Be sure to read the doc of the plugin you choose.

With that out of the way, after importing a module from `a.py`, typing that module name in `b.py` followed by a dot should show a contextual menu with a list of available methods and stuff.