# Autocomplete for gtk3 and pygobject

Tags: python, vim, python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject

I am looking for a possibility to add autocompletion for gtk3 libs to vim. I have already tried vim-jedi as it seems the state of the art autocompletion mechanism for vim and python (also recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138039/vim-autocomplete-for-python)), but that does not work for the gtk3 stuff wich is imported from the gi.repository

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf, Gdk, GObject
```

I took a look into the gi.repository site-packages. After that I am not suprised that jedi is not able to introsepect the methods of the Gtk modules, because these modules a generated there with a lot of magic ;-)

Additionally other "real" IDEs like [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) also does not support completion for the modules which were imported this way (i tried the Community Edition, but I would bet that the Professional Edition also does not support that).

Does anyone have an idea how to add autocompletion to vim (favored solution) or another Editor/IDE?

The GObject, Gtk modules contain quite a lot methods/classes and it's not easy to remebember everything you need. Furthermore there seems to be only documentation for the C api of gtk3, where the method names are not always the same as in python api...

Comment: "Furthermore there seems to be only documentation for the C api of gtk3, where the method names are not always the same as in python api." – That is not true. The introspected bindings are exactly the same API, even with annoyances such as `Gtk.Button.new_with_text`.

Answer (score 2):

[Neocomplcache](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim)/[Neocomplete](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim) are capable of completing introspected GObject libraries *but* it is very likely that this will crash if you did not compile Vim yourself against GTK+ 3. On Ubuntu 14.04, Vim is compiled against GTK+ 2 and trying to import and autocomplete GTK+ 3 libraries will fail because both toolkits cannot run at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Both Jedi and PyCharm support [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/) .pyi type stubs. You can add these type annotation stubs for PyGObject to your editor using the PyGObject-stubs library:

```
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install PyGObject-stubs
```

Both Jedi and PyCharm should pick them up automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found a solution using [fakegir](https://github.com/strycore/fakegir). It builds a fake Python package from the information found in gir files (eg: `/usr/share/gir-1.0/*.gir`). This can provide Gtk autocompletion to your LSP.

Their instructions are straightforward:

- Run `./fakegir.py` to generate the fake package to `~/.cache/fakegir/`
- Create a virtualenv (`mkvirtualenv fakegir` or similar)
- Enter virtualenv directory (`cdvirtualenv fakegir`)
- Enter `./lib/python*/site-packages` directory
- Copy package into the virtualenv: `cp -a ~/.cache/fakegir/gi .`

The virtualenv must be activated before editing your program in vim. The fake package must also be regenerated when you install new gir files or upgrade. I tested this in neovim v0.8.0-dev with [python-lsp-server](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server) (pylsp) and suspect it will work for other language servers.

I also came across the [stubgen](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubgen.html) tool provided by `mypy` which might be
useful for generating type hints/signatures in other situations.